# How to write a jasmine unit test case to test the event handlers in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I am currently writing a jasmine unit test case to test the button's click event. I have written the following test cases for modal popup, please find my plnkr [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/FuYXaKkiQ3tNC3Vu1AL1?p=info). I have a button called Add. If the user clicks the button a modal popup opens. So I want to write a test case to find whether the modal is displayed when the user clicks the add button. How do I do it?
Thanks,
Varun Krishna. P

Answer (score 0):

First of, as with all unit tests, make sure that you're not mixing N tests into one - that always causes trouble.

In your case, the test can be split into 2 tests:

1. Is the correct function called when `Add` is clicked?
2. Does the function display a model dialog?

For the first test, I suggest that you move the code for the event handler into a function instead of in-lining it. That way, you can overwrite the function in the test setup and restore it later (pseudo-code):

```
// setup
var origFunc = addFunction;
var iWasCalled = false;
addFunction = function() { iWasCalled = true; }

// test
$('#add').click();

// validation
assert that iWasCalled is now true

// tear down
addFunction = origFunc
```

The second test means now that you call the new function and check whether there now a modal popup in the DOM.