# Writing Jasmine unit test cases for Modal popup

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine, testcase

This is pretty similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21377684/how-to-write-a-jasmine-unit-test-case-to-test-the-event-handlers-in-angularjs).

I need to write a jasmine test case for Modal pop up. Modal popup is displayed only when the user clicks the button I need to validate whether the pop up is opened and need to write test case for checking the function in pop controller as usual.

Comment: Need more info - what type of modal are you using? What code have you tried, What errors are you getting?

Comment: @PaoloB onClicking the button, whether the pop up is opened or not. 

After opening the pop, I have few functions in popup controller need to write testcase for that as well. As of now I wrote only whethe rmy popup controller is defined or not